# Adding Properties to a feature in Google Earth Engine

Tags: coordinate-system, layers, vector, fields-attributes, google-earth-engine

Is there a way to add a property to a feature in the GEE. I know that you can edit existing properties with *set()*, but haven't found a way to add a property.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `feature.set()`option which [Feature Overview](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/features) covers with these examples:

```js
// Make a feature and set some properties.
var feature = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-122.22599, 37.17605]))
.set('genus', 'Sequoia').set('species', 'sempervirens');

// Get a property from the feature.
var species = feature.get('species');
print(species);

// Set a new property.
feature = feature.set('presence', 1);

// Overwrite the old properties with a new dictionary.
var newDict = {genus: 'Brachyramphus', species: 'marmoratus'};
var feature = feature.set(newDict);

// Check the result.
print(feature);
```

Comment: Oh well, guess i skipped that part :D
Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Sure thing, I'm glad I was able to answer your question.